# How to use getPosition to get the last data entry position? Charts Pod

Tags: swift, charts

I'm trying to add an UIImage for the last data entry point but when I use getPosition the image was in the wrong place. Or there is other way to do it? I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929413/ios-charts-how-to-put-uiimage-beside-a-point) answer but the image position was still off.

```
 if dataPoint.count > 0 {
            for i in 0..<dataPoint.count {
                let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: dataPoint[i].running)
                lineChartEntry.append(value)                
       }
}

 let point = lineChartView.getPosition(entry: lineChartEntry[dataPoint.count - 1], axis: .left)
                let image = UIImage(named: "heart")
                let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
                imageView.frame = CGRect(x: point, y: point, width:15, height: 15)
                lineChartView.addSubview(imageView)
```

[image]

```
> po point  (59.11698190789474, 28.672200520833343)
>   - x : 59.11698190789474
>   - y : 28.672200520833343
```

Comment: Do you want to replace the icon of the last data entry? Can you also post an screenshot of the current behavior?

Comment: @SamB I just edited it with a screenshot. The heart icon was off not on the right place.

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine for me. Could you try setting lineChartDataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = true and plotting circle for each data point. If you could post sample data set which causes this issue, I could investigate more.

Comment: @SamB If I set the drawCirclesEnabled to true the plotting circles are in the correct place. Sample data = dataPoint: [App.Chart(date: 1632182400, value: 0.0), App.Chart(date: 1632268800, value: 0)].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did more research and testing I finally get it working.

In where you are setting the `LineChartDataSet()`

```
//data line setup
let line = LineChartDataSet(entries: lineChartEntry, label: "")
line.mode = .linear                                          
line.colors = [color]                              
line.fillColor = .clear                                     
line.drawFilledEnabled = true
line.drawCirclesEnabled = true

//remove old imageView when the new data comes in
if let viewWithTag = self.view.viewWithTag(100) {
    viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
}

var colors = [UIColor]()
for i in 0..<lineChartEntry.count {
    //only the last circle will show the image
    if(i == lineChartEntry.count - 1) {
        colors.append(color)
        
        let point = lineChartView.getPosition(entry: lineChartEntry[lineChartEntry.count - 1], axis: .left) //get the x and y CGPoint
        let image = UIImage(named: "heart")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
        imageView.tag = (100)
        
        if !point.x.isNaN && !point.y.isNaN {
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: point.x - 15, y: point.y - 15, width:30, height: 30) //set the frame in center
            imageView.contentMode = .center
            lineChartView.addSubview(imageView)
        }
    } else {
        colors.append(UIColor.clear)
    }
}

.
.
.
//other line data configurations
```

Comment: Instead you can do one thing. You can pass 2 dataset. One with all data except last one.. and other with only 1 data. :)